# How to disable a port on a usb hub in Windows 8

Tags: c#, windows-8, usb

I have seen references in the USB 2.0 standard to support for disabling of individual hub ports. I am looking for an API to call from user code in Windows 8, specifically to disable hub ports, either in C# or in C++, using the existing Windows drivers. There is code in DevCon to disable devices in C++, but not to disable hub ports.

I would really appreciate a pointer to the correct user-mode API in Windows 8, or if this is not possible, to know that it doesn't exist.

Thanks -

Comment: Please don't repost questions.

Comment: This is not a repost - I have a question that has not been answered. Before I got back to the original (10 hours) it was closed by 5 people, I think for not being sufficiently specific. I have trimmed the question down significantly.  I am looking for an API to access standard USB functionality in Windows (C#), or to know that it is nonexistent.  If there's a specific problem with my question, please let me know so I can fix it!

Comment: Dana has a good point - voting to reopen the *original* question.  Perhaps considering editing some of these improvements into it?

Comment: The [faq#close] has information about what to do if your question is closed. (Fix it and ask for it to be reopened, or post it on a more appropriate site at [se].) Posting the same question again after it's been closed is a violation of the site guidelines. Please don't do so.

Comment: Thanks for the information. My first closed question.  I am still uncertain as to why the original was closed, but I will shorten it and ask the question more clearly.